# Lodash appending a comma

Tags: javascript, csv, lodash

I cant seem to figure this one out, I am creating a csv string from an object using lodash and I am expecting output looking like this:

```
data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,prop1,prop2,props
d1,d2,n1;n2,d3
d4,d5,n2;n3,d6
d7,d8,n4;n5,d9
```

but what I am getting is this:

```
data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,prop1,prop2,props
d1,d2,n1;n2,d3
,d4,d5,n2;n3,d6
,d7,d8,n4;n5,d9
```

here is how it looks in excel:

[image]

Here is some simplified code that demonstrates the issue:

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,prop1,prop2,props\n",
data = [
    {prop1: "d1", prop2: "d2", props: [{name: "n1"},{name: "n2"}], prop3: "d3" },
    {prop1: "d4", prop2: "d5", props: [{name: "n2"},{name: "n3"}], prop3: "d6" },
    {prop1: "d7", prop2: "d8", props: [{name: "n4"},{name: "n5"}], prop3: "d9" }
];
csvContent +=_.map(data, function(rs) {
    var tmp = {};
    tmp.prop1 = rs.prop1;
    tmp.prop2 = rs.prop2;
    tmp.props = _.map(rs.props, function(r) { return r.name; }).join(';');
    tmp.prop3 = rs.prop3;
    return _.values(tmp).join(",") + '\n';
});
console.log(csvContent);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85ast7n1/)

Comment: but are they not effectively the same (from the point of view of a csv)?

Comment: no, the csv columns do not line up (looking in excel), all rows under the first data row are offset by one to the right.

Comment: You are appending an array to your `csvContent` string--you can just add a `.join('')` to the result of your `map` call.

Comment: @kardeiz *facepalm* thank you, I forgot map returns an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,prop1,prop2,props\n",
data = [
    {prop1: "d1", prop2: "d2", props: [{name: "n1"},{name: "n2"}], prop3: "d3" },
    {prop1: "d4", prop2: "d5", props: [{name: "n2"},{name: "n3"}], prop3: "d6" },
    {prop1: "d7", prop2: "d8", props: [{name: "n4"},{name: "n5"}], prop3: "d9" }
];

stuff = _.map(data, function(rs) {
    var tmp = {};
    tmp.prop1 = rs.prop1;
    tmp.prop2 = rs.prop2;
    tmp.props = _.map(rs.props, function(r) { return r.name; }).join(';');
    tmp.prop3 = rs.prop3;
    return _.values(tmp).join(",");
});

csvContent += stuff.join('\n');

console.log(csvContent);
```

I believe the issue is that you're trying to add `csvContent` (string) and `_.map(...)` (array). Instead, you should just join the array with `\n` and add that to `csvContent`.

http://jsfiddle.net/85ast7n1/1/